How to append a data table from a text file into an SQLite table?
I have an SQLite database which has a table 'myTable' with columns 'Date' and 'Value'. The 'Date' records are unique, that is there is only one row for each date.
I also have a text file with tab delimited "Date" / "Value" pairs.
What is the most efficient way to append the data from the text file into the SQLite table, so that only those  "Date" / "Value" pairs are added which do not already present in the database?
I know how to do it by one row at a time: check if the "Date" / "Value" pair exists in the database, if not then insert it. But that does not seem to be efficient.
I was thinking about something like this: read the text file into a string, convert the string into an array, set DataTable source to the array, update SQLite table from DataTable using DataAdapter.
Is this possible to do and how to do that? Or there is a better way?


check if the "Date" / "Value" pair exists in the database, if not then insert it. But that does not seem to be efficient.

Its more efficient to use the inbuilt UPSERT, MERGE or in SQLites case CONFLICT keywords to be able INSERT OR UPDATE, eg:
INSERT INTO Data (Date, Value)
VALUES ('2024-12-09', 42.0)
ON CONFLICT(Date) DO UPDATE SET
    Value = excluded.Value;

Or if a record exists do nothing:
INSERT INTO Data (Date, Value)
VALUES ('2024-12-09', 42.0)
ON CONFLICT(Date) DO NOTHING;

Otherwise you need to use T-SQL or PL-SQL with a less optimal IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM x WHERE... and then insert, update or do nothing which isn't as efficent.
Here is the code in C#, like you wanted we read the text file into a DataTable, loop through the table inserting records if there is no value for that date.
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // A shorthand way to read CSV file into DataTable
        var dataTable = File.ReadAllLines("data.csv")
            .Skip(1) // Skip header row
            .Select(line => line.Split(','))
            .Aggregate(new DataTable(), (dt, values) =>
            {
                if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(double));
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(values[0], double.Parse(values[1]));
                return dt;
            });

        // Establish SQLite Connection, since its unmanaged wrap it with a Using to close and dispose
        using var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=example.db");
        connection.Open();

        var sql = @"
        INSERT INTO Data (Date, Value)
        VALUES (@Date, @Value)
        ON CONFLICT(Date) DO NOTHING";

        // Loop through each row
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", row["Date"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", row["Value"]);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

If you want to do it in a batch fashion, a DataAdapter is still going to do it row by row. If you want batch, get the start and end dates in the DataTable, query the records within that date range, then in code check if the results from the Database exist in the DataTable, if not concatenate the SQL Insert statements in a StringBuilder and then execute the multiple Insert statements together in one transaction.

Thank you very much for your answer. ON CONFLICT(Date) DO NOTHING is very helpful, I did not know that. Since rows are inserted in the database by one, then creating an intermediate datatabe seems to be redundant. I can just read lines from the original text file. I thought there was a way to append a DataTable in one command. Maybe there is not.

@GreenBear: "I thought there was a way to append a DataTable in one command". There is. You would use a data adapter - presumably a SQLiteDataAdapter in this case - and call its Update method. The SQLiteCommand containing the INSERT statement is assigned to its InsertCommand property and the parameters are configured to take their values from a named DataColumn. See an example here.
